Send audio recording to a C# ASP.NET Web API
I'm attempting to record an audio file on the web using angular / typescript. I am able to successfully record the audio and listen to it with the audio player.  I am attempting to take that audio and send it to a C# ASP.NET Web API post. I've tried converting it to formdata to pass as a file, but that gives me an unsupported media type.
This is the code I use for recording the audio:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferToWave } from './audio-helper'
import { RESTAPIService } from './restapiservice.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AudioRecordingService {
  private chunks: any[] = [];
  private mediaRecorder: any;
  private audioContext: AudioContext = new AudioContext();
  private audioBlobSubject = new Subject<Blob>();
  private stream: any;


  private mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true
  };

  audioBlob$ = this.audioBlobSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private service: RESTAPIService) {
  }

  async startRecording() {
    if (this.audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
      await this.audioContext.resume();
    }

    this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.mediaConstraints);
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream);
    this.mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event: any) => {
        this.chunks.push(event.data);
    };
    this.mediaRecorder.start();
  }

  async stopRecording() {

    if (this.mediaRecorder) {
      let mimeType = this.mediaRecorder.mimeType;

        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
            const audioData = await new Blob(this.chunks).arrayBuffer();
            const audioBuffer = await this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData);
            const wavBlob = bufferToWave(audioBuffer, audioBuffer.length);
            this.audioBlobSubject.next(wavBlob);

            let audioBlob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: mimeType });

            await this.service.postAudio(audioBlob).subscribe(data => {
            });    

            this.chunks = [];
        };

        this.mediaRecorder.stop();

        if (this.stream) {
            this.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track: { stop: () => void; }) {
                track.stop();
            });

            this.stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track: { stop: () => void; }) {
                track.stop();
            });
        }
    }
  }
}

Code to send audio data to the C# ASP.NET Web API:
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    })
  };

  postAudio(blob: Blob)
  {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Test", blob);


    let url = "https://localhost:7048/api/Transcribe/UploadAudio";
    return this.http.post(url, formData);
  }

C# ASP.NET Web API code:
[HttpPost("UploadAudio")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAudio(IFormFile formFile)
{
    return Ok("");
}

I've tried the code above and I was expecting the file to be transferred to the c# api.  Instead I get either a 415 or 400 error.


When using FormData, you don't need to set Content-Type manually. The browser will automatically set the correct Content-Type including the boundary - that's probably causing the HTTP415 error. 2. Make sure you've got CORS setup for everything to start off with  services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins"

